# Raspberry pi class 4 vs Raspberry pi 2 class 10

Tags: sd-card, memory

I currently have the previous raspberry pi class 4 card.
I'm considering getting the new raspberry pi model 2 class 10 card. Is there a speed difference between the two cards?

Comment: [Here's a little something I wrote on the topic a while ago](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/343/40).

Comment: While the other answers regarding the speed are all interesting, please also notice that the Raspberry Pi A and B take a SD card while the Raspberry Pi A+/B+ and 2 takes a **micro** SD card.
You didn't state what Pi and card you own, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhat contra Jivings and Jacobm001, here's a test of two particular cards (class 4 and class 10) I did when I first got a pi:

[Benchmarking SD cards, read speed is identical](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/benchmarking-sd-cards-read-speed-is-identical)

There is a link there to anecdotal results from other people doing the same kind of test with various cards.  Obviously on average class 10 cards are better **but the max read speed of the SD card reader on the pi is 25 MB/s**, regardless of how fancy a card you get.  I believe both class 4 and class 10 are capable of this.

If you are already getting 20 MB/s read, that is something to keep in mind.  Again, a class 10 will be better and is probably worth the few bucks in price difference.

Comment: An actual class 4 card is only good for 4 MB/s. A UHS class of four would be 40 MB/s iirc.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Do you have a reference for that?  Is that a *minimum*?  I am certainly not the only one to report a read speed of 15-20 MB/s with a class 4 card and it is hard to see a flaw in that test method.

Comment: Also, as per Patrick Cook's answer, perhaps *read* and *write* times are getting confused here.

Comment: https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/

Comment: @Jacobm001 That is exactly my point: *"Speed Class designates minimum writing performance to record video."* -> Emphasis on "minimum" and "writing".  It does not say those numbers apply to reads, or represent an upper limit.  I see the telephone game at work here ;)

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the class 4 and class 10 would be extremely obvious on the original RPi, and even more so on the RPi 2.

Even if you're using a read only filesystem, the boot time will be dramatically shorter.

Comment: Class 10 cards have a faster write speed, but almost always this comes with slower read speeds. It shouldn't effect the Pi too much though.

Answer (score 3):

The class of a Micro SD card determines it's write time, NOT it's read time. Class 10 cards usually have a slower read time than Class 4 cards. Class 4 has a fast enough read and write speed for most everything the Pi does, Class 10 cards can have slower boot times, but you should be fine with either.

Source:
https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/

Comment: Do you have references for the relevant specs here?

Comment: @yah, I'll link it in a minute